# How to stop all instances on AWS except one, for example with a certain ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Help me, please, I want to stop all instances, except one, which has for example `Instance ID i-0a5fe830efd1f5df3`. There is such a script, but it stops all instances:

```
$ aws ec2 terminate-instance -instance-ids $ (aws ec2 describe-instances
--filters "Name = instance-state-name, Values = pending, running, stop, stopping"
--query "Reservations []. Instances []. [InstanceId]" --outout text | tr '\ n' '')
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no **single** CLI command to do this operation, as most AWS commands are inclusive, not exclusive.

**I would perform this operation in four steps:**

- First, use `describe-instances` to obtain a list of all instances.
- Iterate through the returned instances, concatenating each instance's ID onto a new variable `instance-ids`. The end result should look like `"instance-id-0" "instance-id-1"` when you `echo` the variable.
- Remove the ID of the instance you want to keep from the `instance-ids` variable
- run `terminate-instances` passing in your trimmed `instance-ids` variable as the `--instance-ids` argument.